# Azure Data Factory Web Activity POST Method error despite success in Postman

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to get a token from an API using Azure Data Factory Web Activity. Below is the Web Activity Settings:

```
{
"name": "GetAPIToken",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "GetAuthToken",
            "type": "WebActivity",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "url": "https://<api_url>",
                "method": "POST",
                "headers": {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                "body": {
                    "value": "@json('{"company_id" : "<value>"}')",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "annotations": []
}
```

}

The above pipeline is giving `403 Forbidden` Error. However, when I am using Postman, I am getting correct response with proper token.

Don't know what exactly I am missing here.

Comment: How do you authenticate in Postman? I don’t see you enabled any authentication in ADF.

Comment: In postman too, no authentication.

Comment: Was Postman run on your laptop which may be on an approved network to call the API? Could you use a Self Hosted Integration Runtime in ADF to call the API from the same network rather than from an Azure network?

Comment: @GregGalloway: Not quite understood what you said. So are you suggesting to use a SHIR in the Web Activity? If I can access the API link from my laptop using postman, then it is safe to assume that API url is public.

Comment: @GregGalloway: I have tried with other API endpoints line `https://reqres.in/api/register` and it is working fine.

Comment: Yes. I’m suggesting you try the web activity from a SHIR. If the API is only allowed from certain IPs that might solve the problem.